# camera orientation issue inside dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, camera, orientation

I am developing an android application for tablets.In my application i am providing barcode scanning feature.I am providing a camera button which will open a dialog box upon button click.Inside the dialog i am showing camera preview.The problem i am facing is about orientation.My application is in landscape mode on revesr landscaple all other elements along with dialog orients accordingly but the camera inside dialog show upside down preview. How to catch the reverse orientation events as configuration changed event is not helpfull here.[image]

Please provide some solutions as i have searched a lot but could not resolve this issue[image]

Comment: can you post ur code here